# WPF .net Framework with MDF file not running when published and installed on another computer

Tags: wpf, publish, mdf

I have created a very simple WPF application which simply reads and displays the contents of a local MDF database. It runs fine on my computer but fails when I publish and install it on another.

I have added a Try/Catch statement around the cm.Open() statement and discovered that it is unable to connect to the database.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. The application is in C#. The local database is an MDF file.

This is my code...

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            GetAllEmployeeRecocrd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        
    }

    private void GetAllEmployeeRecocrd()
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", cn);

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

The only prerequisite which is automatically included is the .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Can anyone offer any ideas please?

Comment: Most obvious reason is that you forgot to install SQL Server.  Next most obvious is that the machine that runs it can't be reached.  Ask IT staff to help you out.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#install-localdb

Comment: @HansPassant. Thank you. You were absolutely right, I had forgotten to add SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add SQL Server. Thank you to Hans Passant